# Putty: Network error: Software caused connection abort

Tags: google-cloud-platform, putty

We've run GCP instances which are about 30 instances on putty for about 3 months. It didn't encounter any errors but recently putty fatal errors occurred and that makes our program stop. I want to know how to fix this issue.

Also, the instances lose network too frequently to work my project. I think the network is weak. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: There are at least three issues: 1) Google moves VMs and reboots VMs (maintenance). 2) SSH server settings keeping connections alive. 3) Network/Internet interruptions such as routers rebooting, your ISP dropping the connection, etc. You need to plan and handle for network interruptions as this is normal in the real networking world. As your question has no details, we can only offer suggestions.

Comment: Please provide more details.